# What is the "permissions icon" called?

Tags: icon

What's the icon highlighted (red box) below called? (In Firefox and Chrome, this button is to access permissions.)

[image]

Also, where can I find this icon (in vector and/or raster)?

Comment: ermm "permissions icon" is what I call it.

Comment: options icon might be another name. Try noun project

Comment: @Scott: But when searching "permissions icon" in Google Images, it doesn't show up much if at all: https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22permissions+icon%22&tbm=isch

Comment: well names of icons are subjective.. search for "security icon" and you get a bunch of different visuals. There's no such thing as one universal visual for most icons.

Comment: It's a very simple icon. Can't you just make your own using a vector app?  You can use something like Inkscape which is a free vector application, or perhaps an online vector app such as Figma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Adjustments icon" seems to give a lot of hits [on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=adjustments%20icon). Seems to exist on many big icon libraries, [Lucide icons](https://lucide.dev/icons/?search=settings) is an example of an open source one you could use.